# Android can't find method removeAccount

Tags: android

I have implemented accounts for my app following this tutorial http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

Every aspect of the implementation works great except when I try to remove the account with the following code:

```
    public void logout(View view) {
    // remove account and restart app
    stopService(new Intent(this, ServerSync.class));
    Account account = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE)[0];
    final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = AccountManager.get(this).removeAccount(account, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            try {
                future.getResult();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }, null);
}
```

When called this produces

```
NoSuchMethodError: android.accounts.AccountManager.removeAccount
```

and the app crashes.

I have followed the Android documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

and my app has the correct permissions etc. I even tried overriding getAccountRemovalAllowed in my AccountAuthenticator, forcing it to return true.

Is there some other information missing from the Android documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the version of removeAccount you are using was introduced with the api leve 22 and you are probably using it on a version of Android older than it. You should check the current version at runtime and use the deprecated version of `removeAccount` for devices with version of Android older than 22

[removeAccount (Account account, AccountManagerCallback callback, Handler handler)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeAccount(android.accounts.Account,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E,%20android.os.Handler))

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
    AccountManager.get(this).removeAccount(account, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>(){....}, null) 
} else {
   // the version you are already using
}
```